# Cannot resolve overloaded method fromJson

Tags: scala, jsonb, payara

I am migrating my projects from Payara4 to Payara5 and one of these projects is in Scala.

I'm switching Jackson to JSON-B, and when trying to deserialize a JSON string in an object, the IDE reports the error: **Cannot resolve overloaded method 'fromJson'**.

```
val xpto: Xpto = jsonb.fromJson(json, Xpto.class)
```

My **Xpto** class is an entity with its getters and setters.

Any idea how to solve this?

**EDIT 1**

After run the command `mvn clean install` I received the error `identifier expected but 'class' found`, so I removed the `.class` and ran again the maven command and the error changed to `Xpto is not a value`.

**EDIT 2**

After change the code to `val xpto: Xpto = jsonb.fromJson(json, classOf[Xpto])` started to work.

Answer (score 1):

After change the code to `val xpto: Xpto = jsonb.fromJson(json, classOf[Xpto])` started to work.